# How to I use MKVmerge to add sbtitles to MKV but disable all of them

Tags: subtitles, matroska

I came across mkvmerger.bat on this site and it works really well for me ([How to mkvmerge all videos and subtitles with the same file name](https://superuser.com/questions/1378960/how-to-mkvmerge-all-videos-and-subtitles-with-the-same-file-name))
BUT
It seems to set the last subtitle file as the default (which then plays when the video is played)

I want the viewer to have no subtitles unless they specifically select a set of subtitles so how can I mod the script to set no subtitle as the default or 'disable subtitles'.
Thanks in advance

Update
https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/403722-Add-multiple-Subtitles-to-Video-File provides a script that takes subtitles from a subdirectory and adds them to an MKV video file of the same name.

This routine sets the default to 'no subtitles' which is what I want
The author suggests that  adding "--default-track 0:no” before the name of the corresponding subroutine file should do the trick (and it certainly seems to)

I have tried adding the magic text "--default-track 0:no" in various places so, for example:
mkvmerge.exe -o "%mkvTarget%" --default-track 0:no "%mkvSources%"
or
IF EXIST "%mkvTargetName%.idx" SET "mkvSources=%mkvSources%" --default-track 0:no "%mkvTargetName%.idx"
but this has not had the desired effect

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried so far.

Comment: Edited as requested